# Rails rspec stub mailers sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I was wondering how I can stub all mailers in my rspec tests? I noticed that I am currently delivering emails when running my tests.

Thank you

Edit:

I'm using sidekiq to delay deliver emails, as well as gem 'devise-async' to deliver emails in the background.

config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test still delivers emails.

Answer (score 0):

You can use...

```
YourMailer.stub_chain(:delay, :send_method)
```